# How to turn object.__dict__ into the object itself again?

Tags: python

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Node(5)
    print a # prints __main__.Node object at 0x025C7530
    print a.__dict__ # how can I turn this back into the previous line?
```

Is there anyway to turn the **dict** back into the object?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? If the property wasn't read-only, you'd end up with an endlessly recursive object.

Comment: A function I am using "gc.get_referrers" only returns the dictionary of the object instead of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some types of objects, you can get an identical object (not the object itself, but a copy):

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Node(5)
    a = a.__dict__ #whoops, now I lost the object, I just have the dict
    b = Node.__new__(Node) # make a new empty object
    b.__dict__ = a.copy() # copy in the dict
    # copy because there might still a reference to the object elsewhere
    # if you want changes to b to affect a, then don't copy just assign
    print b.__dict__
    print b
```

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, you can't (without modifying the `Node` class). The `__dict__` does not keep a reference to the original object. You can accomplish something *similar* by copying the dict:

```
n1 = Node(5)
n2 = Node.__new__(Node) # object created but not initiated.
n2.__dict__ = n1.__dict__
n1.foo = 'something fooish'

print n1.foo == n2.foo #True
```

Unfortunately, `n1 != n2`.

Answer (score 0):

I only know it is possible for old-style classes in Python 2:

```
class Ode(): # not derived from object
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

>>> o = Ode(6)
>>> o.data
6

>>> import new
>>> od = o.__dict__
>>> od
{'data': 6}
>>> new.instance(Ode, od).data
6
>>> new.instance(Ode, {'data': 666}).data
666
```

But note that this is not the same as copying the object and I feel you may run into various weird issues doing that (just to mention one: object's constructor isn't called).